# Entire program watching via debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I want to inspect each and every object (that has at least one reference) in a program  and I want to do it at any time the programs execution is paused (via breakpoint, for example).

If I add a variable (object) to Watch of Parallel watch, it doesn't allow me to inspect it unless whatever part of program is executing is within the same scope as the variable.

How do I inspect a variable (object) at any give scope, globally?

How do I track a variable from start of the program (or from when it's first defined) up until the end of it's execution?

In the project I'm working on, each and every object has a direct or indirect reference from the topmost object, a Form. If I could inspect it at all times, I would have access to any other object in my program.

How do I do it? There must be a (simple) way, it would seem as a huge oversight not to enable the programmer to analyze it's program whole at any time (when the execution is paused).

[Sorry for doubling the question, I deleted the old one, I hope this one is more clear.]

Comment: Do you have a more specific example of an object you're trying to inspect?  It sounds like you want to inspect things which aren't currently in scope, which doesn't really make sense.  (For example, a variable inside of a function that isn't currently executing.)

Comment: I have some wierd problem and it's related to some kind of referencing issues. I have an object that is referenced by a bunch of other objects (or at least it should be). Rather than analyzing the code which could take hours (and what I already did and failed) It'd be so much simple to simply run the program, list all the variables I'm interested in and see which one is the problem, if that even is a problem. I'm very surprised that this isn't something you can do by a click of a button, it seems like a rather powerfull and in some cases essential debbuging option.

Comment: `"list all the variables I'm interested in"` - And how is the IDE supposed to know what variables meet that criteria?  I'm not at all surprised that this feature doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, it would list ALL of the variables, and then I'd look at the ones I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the variable is in scope, right click on the variable you want to track in the Watch/Locals window and select "Make Object ID".  You can then see the value of the object referenced by the variable even when you are in a different scope.  See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/03/04/make-object-id/) for more info.

Comment: Well would you look at that. There is a simple way. Thank you very much, you have been a great help. =)

Answer (score -1):

There's a window called `Locals` that you can access that contains all attributes currently instanced in the program. 
You can open it when debugging via the menu Debug->Windows->Locals.

Comment: Locals wont track variables out of scope which is what he wants.

Comment: In that case, I think the only way is to enable address-level debugging and tracking memory directly, but that's not very easy to do.
Also, you can make object IDs, but that only works for declared variables, and you would have to make each ID yourself.

Comment: I can't believe that there is no simple way to track a single variable throughout the whole program, or at least from the variables initialization.

Comment: A single variable you can, here: http://abhijitjana.net/2010/10/20/how-to-track-an-object-which-is-out-of-scope-while-debugging/

It teaches you how to make the object IDs I mentioned above.